# Convert hibernate query to criteria

Tags: hibernate, criteria

How to convert hibernate sql query in criteria :

```
String hql = "from OMRDetailsTable omrDetailsTable " +
            "where omrDetailsTable.bar_code_no not in(" +
            "select roll_no from RejectListTable rejectListTable where rejectListTable.rej_status='R') " +
            "and omrDetailsTable.roll_no not in(" +
            "select roll_no from RejectListTable rejectListTable where rejectListTable.rej_status='R') " +
            "and omrDetailsTable.omr_error in('T','U') order by omrDetailsTable.roll_no";
```

I have tried to convert it but it throws this exception : `could not resolve property: parent of: com.templateproject.table.OMRDetailsTable`

```
DetachedCriteria subCriteria =     DetachedCriteria.forClass(RejectListTable.class);
  subCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("rej_status", 'R'));
  subCriteria.setProjection(Projections.property("roll_no"));
  subCriteria.setProjection(Projections.property("error_type"));

  Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(OMRDetailsTable.class);
  criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("omr_error", 'T'));
  criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("omr_error", 'U'));
  criteria.add(Subqueries.propertyEq("parent", subCriteria));
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You need only one projection

```
DetachedCriteria subCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(RejectListTable.class);
subCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("rej_status", 'R'));
subCriteria.setProjection(Projections.property("roll_no"));
```

And, please, use `Subqueries.notIn()` with `roll_no` (not `parent`)

```
Subqueries.notIn("roll_no", subCriteria)
```

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty I think no. You use `criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("omr_error", 'T')); criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("omr_error", 'U'));` for `in('T','U')` It is incorrect. Try to begin from a simply query with a subquery.